# Not able to access public property from ts file in Html file

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript

I need to get some data from service and display it in HTML. I have put API call in service, and I got that data in ts file(checked in console), But When I am trying to get the same data into html, its showing null reference exception. Couldnt figure out what I missed.

```
export class SsoComponent implements OnInit {  
  public samlResponseData: SamlResponse;  
  constructor(
    private ssoService: SsoService,   
    private store: Store<AppState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {   
    this.verifySessionExpiration();
   }

  public verifySessionExpiration() {    
    this.store.pipe(select(getAuthData))
      .subscribe(authData => {
        if (authData) {
          this.ssoService.fetchSamlResponse()
            .subscribe(samlResponse => {
              console.log(samlResponse);
              this.samlResponseData = samlResponse;
            });
        } else {
           this.ssoService.goLogin();
        }
       });
   }
```

I am seeing the correct response in console. This is my code in HTML.

```
{{samlResponseData.ResponseData}}
```

I am getting a console error saying, "Unable to set property 'ResponseData' of undefined or null reference"

I have a model SamlResponse with a string property that I want to show it in HTML.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The logic you have in `verifySessionExpiration()` asynchronous. You are getting that error because your template is trying to access `samlResponseData` before it has a value.

One way to fix it would be to only render the data when you know the value isn't null or undefined.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="samlResponseData">
    {{samlResponseData.ResponseData}}
</ng-container>
```

Another option would be to initialize `samlResponseData` to some empty object:

```
samlResponseData = {};
```